# Having an ASMX web service inside a dotnetnuke module

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have implemented a DNN module that works fine. Now my employer wants me to expose some of the features as web services.I want to keep everything clean and simple so I decided to add an asmx web service to my module.

The web service itself was working fine but when I tried to add a HttpModule to handle request authentication everything was messed up.

I have an event handler for `AuthenticateRequest` as follow :

```
private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (app == null || !(app.Request.Url.ToString().EndsWith("WebServices.asmx"))) return;
            var request = app.Request;
            var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader != null)
            {
                var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

                // RFC 2617 sec 1.2, "scheme" name is case-insensitive
                if (authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("basic",
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    authHeaderVal.Parameter != null)
                {
                    AuthenticateUser(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;    
            }
        }
```

and here's the client side :

```
var service = new localhost.WebServices();
            var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache
            {
                {new Uri(service.Url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("user", "password")}
            };

            service.Credentials = credentialsCache;
            Console.WriteLine(service.HelloWorld());
```

The problem is no Authorization header is added to my request this way. I searched and I found out that there was a round trip here that the header was not added for the first time and if response had a basic authorization header ,another request was sent with the header. Thus I added the else part :

```
else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;    
                }
```

and an EndRequest handler :

```
private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            if (response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                    string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
            }
        }
```

Now every time I send a request I am redirected to login page !!!(I know that this happens because there is another `FormAuthentication HttpModule` that redirects the request to login page if `StatusCode` is 401)

Please tell me what am I doing wrong ?(is there a way to prevent the other `HttpModule` to interfere with my response ? )

**UPDATE**

I set `PreAuthenticate` property to true  but still no authorization header is sent

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: That was not a tag :) That shows the scope of the question ( I meant I wasn't talking about web services in general but inside a dotnetnuke module)

Comment: than you'd be better off adding the scope to your question, instead of using tag-style like *tag - title* (which you actually did with your last edit)